# Super simple email validation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a really simple email validation script that basically just checks the following

1. that the email isn't blank
2. the the email contains an @ symbol with at least 1 character before it
3. that there is a domain ie @ with at least 2 letters after it
4. that it ends with a fullstop with at least 2 letters after it

I know there are many more checks, but I look at these regex rules and my mind stops working. I figure if I started with something small like this I might be able to wrap my brain around more complex rules.

Currently using some jQuery I do the following:

```
 var booking_email = $('input[name=booking_email]').val();

 if(booking_email == '' || booking_email.indexOf('@') == -1 || booking_email.indexOf('.') == -1) {

   // perform my alert

 }
```

This is enough to stop 90% of bogus emails so far... I would just like to make it a bit more effective because currently my rule will allow emails like '@example.com' or '`user@domain`.' because it only checks that there is a fullstop and an @ symbol.

Comment: A tool that might help with RegEx is [this Analyzer](http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html).

Comment: u prefer a solution with regex or plain simple javascript ?

Comment: plain simple javascript.. regex is probably better but I don't like the unintuitive formatting of it.

Comment: I don't like using code I can't look at and easily understand ie copy and pasting regex stuff. Simply because if I get a complaint about an email not working, I can't look at it simply and get a good idea as to why the script isn't working.

Comment: About two years ago I wrote this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation/300862#300862

Comment: Regarding the 3rd check - there *are* single letter domains.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain

Comment: fun fact: domains [don't need a dot in the slightest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20573804/740553), you can send emails to `someone@localhost` just fine. So with that said: just use `<input type="email">` in a form and make it do the validation for you, instead of rolling your own code? Browsers kind of have this built in already.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

What others have suggested should work fine, but if you want to keep things simple, try this:

```
var booking_email = $('input[name=booking_email]').val();

if( /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(booking_email) ){
  // valid email
} else {
  // invalid email
}
```

Even if you decide to go with something more robust, it should help you understand how simple regex can be at times. :)

Comment: nice, you posted like 11 seconds before me. albeit this RegExp is kind of correct, there's no need to use capturing parens, you should use `test` instead of `search` and it's always a good practice to anchor your RegExps.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "anchor[ing] your RegExps", but you're right, `text` is faster than `search`. :)

Comment: the `^` at the start and `$` at the end are 'anchors'. They dictate that the string must exactly begin with what comes next to the ^, and end with what comes before the $. A simple way to view this is that `/a/` will match against ' a', but `/^a/` will not.

Comment: Oh right, yes. Is it important in this example though, will the above match something it should not, where the anchored version wouldn't? Or would anchoring it only be important if the regex was a little bit more complex, i.e. not accepting spaces within the string?

Comment: Can it be changed to allow only one `@` sign in email id?

Comment: `/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test('d  @  . df ')` Is also true... I think you can do better.

Comment: I mean, this is clearly just wrong. It should either be fixed or at least not accepted as the answer.

Comment: isn't this redundant? `(.+){2,}` it means "any character one or more times, at least two or more times"  ...  shouldn't it just be `.{2,}`

Comment: @Francisc0 Or even shorter `..+`.

Comment: Quite simple, but also ```"yeah! I love... @ - . @ . @x"``` would validate,
I'd rather suggest:
```new RegExp("^([^\@ ]+)\@(([^\@ .]+){2,}\.)+([^\@ .]+){2,}$")```

Comment: There is something very wrong with this regex, DO NOT USE.

This is the second regex we try that causes issues.

This one hangs the CPU on large emails as: 
somelargeruser@someevenlargerdomainname.com

Answer (score 61):

The least possible greedy validation you an do is with this RegExp `/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/`

It will only ensure that the address fits within the most basic requirements you mentioned: a character before the @ and something before and after the dot in the domain part (`\S` means "anything but a space"). Validating more than that will probably be wrong (you always have the chance of blacklisting a valid email).

Use it like this:

```
function maybeValidEmail (email) { return /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(email); }
```

Comment: This is good for what I was looking for. I'll do more validation on the back end, but it's convenient to allow JS to at least weed out the more obvious fakes.

Comment: this is better than the accepted answer.  What do you think about taking it one step further and using the "non whitespace" shortcut like this `\S+@\S+\.\S+` ?  because right now the `.` will also accept whitespace characters which shouldn't be allowed in an email

Comment: Ditto @Francisc0 right now, you can submit "hello @world.com" - but yeah, good regex

Comment: You should restrict the @ sign instead of allowing any character like in geedew's answer.  Otherwise this allows any number of @ signs.  Even simply "@@@.@" will pass.

Comment: "Otherwise this allows any number of @ signs". It's still a valid email to have more than one @ sign.

Comment: Nice that this solution also works for non-English emails.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
function valid_email(email) {
   return email.match(/^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]{1})|[a-z])\.)+[a-z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$/i);
}
```

That is the **best available email validation regex**, according to [this article](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php). I recommend using this, unless your goal is something really simple but not fully compatible.

Comment: This doesn't return a true/false match as it does all patterns that may match valid email patterns. It should return email.test(....); even so - it returns false on valid patterns containing special characters unless you specifically exclude them from the validation (such as ') via something like escape() [which also kills it] --- as posted in an earlier comment, all of the "maybe" characters make effective regex nearly impossible. Best to test with a simple routine followed by email validation: http://www.remote.org/jochen/mail/info/chars.html (this is based solely on RFC validation)

Comment: this is now wrong, the TLD portion [a-z]{2,6} is out of date, that needs to be [a-z]{2,18} (YES, 18 Letters) because of the TLDs like .NORTHWESTERNMUTUAL and .TRAVELERSINSURANCE

Answer (score 2):

RegexLib.com ( http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email ) has hundreds of email validation routines for a reason. I'd recommend you read this article: http://www.unwrongest.com/blog/email-validation-regular-expressions/ and if you decide to continue using regex for validation, my favorite testing utility is the free regex designer available for free here: http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/ ... test all emails in a LARGE list (available for free download or purchase ... or use your own current DB) to ensure your regex is acceptable within your constraints.

I would recommend a basic test (many at the top of regexlib.com ... I'm not taking credit for the work of theirs I use routinely), followed by a email validation routine that requires user interaction. It is the only real way to 'validate' an email address.

Answer (score 1):

Emails are very difficult to test, but you can have a somewhat restrictive, but simple email validation. I use this one myself, which does a pretty decent job of making sure it's 95% an email address.

```
var simpleValidEmail = function( email ) {
    return email.length < 256 && /^[^@]+@[^@]{2,}\.[^@]{2,}$/.test(email);
};
```

I would recommend this for a 'simple' validation.

To see why this is a hard thing to solve, see: [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

**Update**: corrected regular expression

Comment: This throws: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[^@]+@[^@]+{2,}\.[^@]+{2,}$/: Nothing to repeat` when used in recent Chrome.

Comment: @JimmyBlu the `+` are uneeded... it should be: `/^[^@]+@[^@]{2,}\.[^@]{2,}$/`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var booking_email = $('input[name=booking_email]').val();
if(booking_email.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)) {
  // valid email
} else {
  // not valid
}
```

Comment: You are too restrictive. For example you don't allow the + sign in the name part, used by gmail to tag mails. And before a test on the domain part is done, it has to be converted to punycode or you don't support IDN. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation/300862#300862

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Ian Christian Myers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4964745/5078168) reply before this, this answer adds + sign and extend to tld with more than 4 chars

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="email" name="email" required>
```

This should work I guess.

type = email will check for basic validations and required will check if the field is blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NPM plugin which is very easy to use and is also very powerful. Its `super-easy-validator` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/super-easy-validator).

Here is how you can use this plugin to check email:

```js
const Validator = require('super-easy-validator')
const rules = { email: 'email' };
const data = { email: booking_email };
const { errors } = Validator.validate(rules, data)
if(errors) {
  console.log(errors);
}
```

Its not just about email, there are many more features and you can't write every single validator by yourself as its not possible for very large projects. I recommend you to go through the docs of this library, it will save lots of your time in the long run

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check only for Business Emails then try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
     $('#sendReq').click(function(){ 
     var email = $('#emailAddress').val();
     var reg = /^([\w-\.]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!hotmail.com)(?!yahoo.co.in)(?!aol.com)(?!abc.com)(?!xyz.com)(?!pqr.com)(?!rediffmail.com)(?!live.com)(?!outlook.com)(?!me.com)(?!msn.com)(?!ymail.com)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
      if (reg.test(email)){
     return 0;
     }
     else{
     alert('Please Enter Business Email Address');
     return false;
     }
     });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please don't do this

Comment: Your solution excludes many valid email addresses, including anything with a TLD longer than 4 characters.

Answer (score -1):

The [`is-email`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-email) package on npm is [super simple](https://github.com/segmentio/is-email/blob/master/lib/index.js), if a little loose, just:

```
var matcher = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;

function isEmail(string) {
  return matcher.test(string);
}
```

It was written by segment.io, who deal with a lot of emails.

Comment: isEmail('aa@acom') -> true