# My input type="text" is not validating my email address correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, forms

```
function valid(valid){

    if (valid.value !== null && valid.value !== ""){
        valid.id = "success";
}}

function validEmail(valid){

    var atpos = valid.value.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = valid.value.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (atpos > 0 && dotpos > atpos+1 && dotpos+2 < valid.length){
        valid.id = "success";
}}
```

When a user types a email address into a text box, I am using `onkeyup` to call the function `validEmail()`.  Even when I type in a valid email address the id does not change to "success." (All that `id="success"` does is turn the input to a green background.)

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  I want the textbox to turn green when a valid email is entered.

Also, I call the same function on onsubmit, and it works then.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `type="email"` and let the browser validate it for you.

Comment: @Oriol type email is HTML5 dependent. You can't rely on it

Comment: I want to style it when it's validated.  Like turn green when it's correct and red when it's wrong.

Comment: @ArtOfCode: Even if input type = 'email' is html5 dependent it is a good practice to use it. just ensure fallback support for older browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is calling "valid.length" which is not defined.

The fixed code would be:

```
function validMe(object){ 
    var atpos = object.value.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = object.value.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (atpos > 0 && dotpos > atpos+1 && dotpos+2 < object.value.length) {
        object.id = "success";
    }
}
```

Tested on http://jsfiddle.net/suugqrdz/

Also, as a suggestion, use regex to validate emails, it's easier and more reliable than coming up with one on your own.

**Edit for Regex**

```
function validMe(object){ 
    var atpos = object.value.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = object.value.lastIndexOf(".");

    if(atpos < 0 && dotpos < 0) {
        object.id = "default";
        return; //So you don't test unnecessarily
    }

    //var againAnotherMatch = /.+@.+\..+/;
    //var anotherMatch = /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/;
    var match = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (match.test(object.value)) {
        object.id = "success";
    }
    else {
        object.id = "default";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suugqrdz/1/

Comment: How could I do that with regex?

Comment: @Godisgood Edited the answer with regex. That's one of the many matches you can do for email, you can check for others or even come up with one yourself. Regex is really powerful for validations and such, and although it may seem intimidating at first, it's really easy to learn and do simple validations with it.

Comment: _Simple_? That regex is both horrendous and wrong - it can't handle non-Latin domains and TLDs, for one. I don't want to look further, but I believe there would be other stuff that's wrong with it. And since it's horrendous, it's really annoying and hard to debug or maintain. Just check for an `@` and a dot. OP did have the correct idea, and it's by far the best email validation I've seen without using regex. With regex, it would be `/.+@.+\..+/` this says "there would be at least one symbol then an @, then at least one symbol, then a dot, then at least one symbol".

Comment: @Vld To be honest, I simply copy and pasted from a project around here... I did left another simple one that also goes similar to this one, except it limits the characters after the `@` by 2 (I never saw an email with less than 2 characters after the `.`). I'm going to put your RegExp in there as well if you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks, both of you.  I'm going with the simpler one by @Vld.  To be honest, I've never done regex, and you have inspired me to learn it.  Are there any resources for learning regex that you would reccomend?

Comment: Technically, valid email addresses don't even need to have a dot: `email@localhost` is perfectly valid, assuming you are hosting an email server. A more realistic example would be `email@server` where "server" is a machine local to your network, say, in a corporate network, and the DNS can happily resolve that name for you. But most emails people would use on the net would have them. And yes, if they do have a dot, they'd most likely have more than one, but `plan.b` is a valid (even if not recommended) machine name. Finally, you'rejust catching people mistyping - to validate, send an email.

Comment: @Godisgood for resources, there are bound to be a lot of online tutorials. I've come upon http://www.regular-expressions.info/ before and it seems to have good information, also definitely worth checking out http://regex101.com/ - it lets you build and test your regexes and it even gives you information about what they do, if you just want to test other people's.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to validate email addresses yourself I recommend you use a plugin to achieve what you are looking for. There are some edge cases that would fail your validation but would in fact still be valid email addresses.

I recommend you utilise the following plugin

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Or if you feel this solution is (as dave pointed out) too overkill for you needs. See this post for a great simple example.

[Super simple email validation with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964691/super-simple-email-validation-with-javascript)

Comment: A bit over kill just to validate an email don't you think to install and a library plugin ?

Comment: Perhaps but I'm sure there are many demonstrated simple examples that would better suit the users needs. Such as this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964691/super-simple-email-validation-with-javascript

Comment: You've fallen for the `just use jQuery` habit. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif this too. Essentially an answer suggesting to just use jQuery is not a valid answer.

Comment: Oh totally. Or. A recommendation based upon an open source plugin that has extensive and active development / contribution? And. A link to a popular post with a demonstrated simple example. Yikes

Comment: Then use it as a comment. Because it doesn't actually answer the question.